# can I use have seen in this sentence

Tags: present-perfect

Can I say if I'm talking on the phone while I am walking around, and I saw a flower few minutes ago.

- I have seen a flower, it's weird because it's not the season.

Should I use "just"?

Comment: I just saw a flower, it's weird because it is out of season.

Comment: Why do you want to use the present perfect at all?  The action of seeing the flower is entirely in the past, so the past tense is a more natural choice.

Comment: @stangdon - A British English speaker would use the present perfect here.

Comment: @KateBunting  I get the feeling that British English uses the present perfect more than American English does - it's not that AmE doesn't use it at all, of course, but it seems more specifically limited.  I wonder if there's a good overview of that anywhere.

Comment: @stangdon - So do I. Recently I've started noticing adverts saying "[Our product] just got better", but I find the usage jarringly American. See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/308619/what-did-have-you-just-say-said).

Comment: @stangdon - and [this blog](https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2006/08/present-perfect.html)

Comment: @KateBunting That's a good post.  I feel like this bit is particularly relevant to ELL - *In general, though perhaps more in BrE than in AmE, the present perfect is used to signal recency* - because learners sometimes come in with one interpretation of the PP or another based on where their teacher is from!

Answer (score 1):

Using "just" helps to give the sense of "a few minutes ago". So you can use "just" because that is what you mean.  There's no grammar reason why you must you "just".